# Bluetooth 4.0 : Access Bluetooth Classic section through Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth

I am building some software on mac os x that uses iobluetooth and corebluetooth to connect/manipulate bluetooth devices.

Like most Bluetooth speakers, the Bluetooth classic network is hidden unless pairing but often the Bluetooth Low Energy network is visible.

I was wondering if there was some way to find a link to the Bluetooth classic section through the Bluetooth Low Energy network and use the details to establish a connection to the Bluetooth classic network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that your speaker is supporting both LE and classic Bluetooth profiles.

So you can connect le first by giving BD_ADDR and all the details for your speaker and later on you can change the transport to classic Bluetooth such as A2DP or SCO.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, do you know any articles on this where I can learn how to perform this? that would be really helpful :)

Comment: You can download core spec version 5 from below link    https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification